# Gin problem using GWT and Guice. - java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 

Tags: gwt, guice, gwt-gin

I have a problem using Gin. Here is a simple example.

```
@GinModules(AppModule.class)
public interface AppInjector extends Ginjector
{
  MainForm getMainPanel();
  TemplateForm getHeaderForm();
}
```

then here is Module

```
import com.google.inject.Singleton;
    public class AppModule extends AbstractGinModule
    {
    @Override
    protected void configure()
    {
      bind(MainForm.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
    }
```

and the Entry point

```
public class MySampleApplication implements EntryPoint

private final AppInjector injector = GWT.create(AppInjector.class);

public void onModuleLoad()
{
  MainForm mf = injector.getMainPanel();
  RootPanel.get().add(mf);
}
}
```

And the module xml file

```
<module rename-to="MySampleApplication">

    <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                  -->
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

    <!-- Specify the app entry point class.                   -->
    <entry-point class='com.mySampleApplication.client.MySampleApplication'/>

    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.inject.Inject"/>

    <!-- Specify the app servlets.                   -->
    <servlet path='/MySampleApplicationService' class='com.mySampleApplication.server.MySampleApplicationServiceImpl'/>

</module>
```

After i run this code i got an exception :

ERROR: Failed to create an instance of 'com.mySampleApplication.client.MySampleApplication' via deferred binding . java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'com.mySampleApplication.client.gin.AppInjector' (did you forget to inherit a required module?).

I tried with gin 1.0 and guice 2.0.

Please, advice.

Thanks.

Comment: Your code looks OK to me. Have you checked that you have all required files in the classpath: AFAIK you need gin.jar, guice.jar, aopalliance.jar

Comment: There must be other errors reported to guide you, hinting exactly what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@GinModules(AppClientModule.class)
```

should probably be

```
@GinModules(AppModule.class)
```

**Update:**

The error is in line declaring `AppInjector`. It should be:

```
interface AppInjector extends Ginjector {
```

Comment: I would wish this to be the problem but it's not. :) Thanks Peter.

Comment: Do you have '<inherits name="com.google.gwt.inject.Inject"/>` in your .gwt.xml file?

Comment: Yes, i have edited my post including the xml module file.. Any other ideas?

Comment: Does your `MainForm` have a no-arg constructor?

Comment: There is no no-arg constructor, is it matters? by the way the exception is thrown on this line : private final AppInjector injector = GWT.create(AppInjector.class); So i don't think the problem is in the no-arg constructor, what do you think?

Comment: If there is no constructor then Java creates a default no-arg constructor. However if you have a constructor with args, but no no-arg constructor, then java does not create one. In this case GIN will throw an error, because it does not know how to instantiate a class.

Comment: Other possibility might be that you are missing a jar. For Gin to work you must have: Gin, Guice and Aopalliance jars on your path.

Comment: Based on where you get the error, I lean towards a missing jar.

Comment: Yes, it could be but i can't figure out which jar is missing. I downloaded gin 1.5 and put it's jars in the path of my project and also in directory lib under war. Anything else i m missing?

Comment: GIN 1.5 has two jars: one for GWT 2.2+ and one for GWT <2.2. Which GWT version do you use? You should only use one gin jar not both.

Comment: Yes i got the one for 2.2+ because my GWT is 2.3

Comment: I have created a small project, just to setup GIN. Do you want to send you a zip file to take a look ?

Comment: OK, post URL to zip here. I'll take a look.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Here it is http://www.4shared.com/file/hzc-qjdl/gwt-gintar.html
Let me know if you figure out any solution.

Comment: It was pretty obvious when IDEA said `Deferred binding result type 'com.mySampleApplication.client.gin.AppInjector' should not be abstract`. You forgot to post this line as it is the most important error line.

Comment: Yes i see now. Thanks Peter. i wish to give you rate but i dont have reputation.